# I want to search, delete and update from a text file in C#

Tags: c#

Like the title, I want to search, delete and update from a text file. I've a menu, an add functions and a view all functions but I couldn't figure out how to do search, delete and update from a text file.

*edit:*

text file example:

```
stdID|stdName|stdPhone|stdAge|stdGrading
00001|John|17158721|17|B
00002|Alex|31992592|17|A
```

So for the search function. I want to have the user input the ID and they get the entire string of information from the text file.

For delete function. I want the user to input the ID and the entire string of information with the exact ID will be delete from the text file.

For Update, I want the user to input the ID and they can re-enter the information of the string into the text file.

Here is the menu, add and view functions.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool showMenu = true;
        while (showMenu)
        {
            showMenu = MainMenu();
        }
    }

    private static bool HandleError(string message)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return true;
    }

    private static bool MainMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("=======================");
        Console.WriteLine(" Choose an option:");
        Console.WriteLine("  1. Manage Students");
        Console.WriteLine("  2. Manage Lecturers");
        Console.WriteLine("  3. Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("=======================");
        Console.Write("\r\nPlease choose: ");

        try
        {
            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1":
                    ManageStudents();
                    return true;
                case "2":
                    ManageLecturers();
                    return true;
                case "3":
                    return false;
                default:
                    return HandleError("!! Invalid input !!");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return HandleError("!! Execution error !!");
        }

    }

    private static bool ManageStudents()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("========================");
        Console.WriteLine(" Choose an option:");
        Console.WriteLine("  1. Add a new student");
        Console.WriteLine("  2. View all students");
        Console.WriteLine("  3. Search students");
        Console.WriteLine("  4. Delete students");
        Console.WriteLine("  5. Update students");
        Console.WriteLine("  6. Back to main menu");
        Console.WriteLine("========================");
        Console.Write("\r\nPlease choose: ");

        Program program = new Program();

        try
        {
            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1":
                    program.AddStudents();
                    return true;
                case "2":
                    ViewStudents();
                    return true;
                case "3":
                    SearchStudents();
                    return true;
                case "4":
                    DeleteStudents();
                    return true;
                case "5":
                    UpdateStudents();
                    return true;
                case "6":
                    return false;
                default:
                    return HandleError("!! Invalid input !!");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return HandleError("!! Execution error !!");
        }
    }

    struct Student
    {
        public int stdID;
        public string stdName;
        public int stdPhone;
        public int stdAge;
        public string stdGrading;
    }

    private Student tStudent;
    static FileStream F;
    StreamWriter W;
    StreamReader R;

    private void AddStudents()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.Write("Enter student ID: ");
        tStudent.stdID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter student full name: ");
        tStudent.stdName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter student phone number: ");
        tStudent.stdPhone = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter student age: ");
        tStudent.stdAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter student grading: ");
        tStudent.stdGrading = Console.ReadLine();

        F = new FileStream(@"C:\Text\students.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        W = new StreamWriter(F);

        W.Write(tStudent.stdID);
        W.Write("|");
        W.Write(tStudent.stdName);
        W.Write("|");
        W.Write(tStudent.stdPhone);
        W.Write("|");
        W.Write(tStudent.stdAge);
        W.Write("|");
        W.Write(tStudent.stdGrading);
        W.Write("|");

        W.Flush();
        W.Close();
    }

    private static void ViewStudents()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Text\students.txt")
                        .Select(x => x.Split('|'))
                        .ToArray();

        var widths = Enumerable.Range(0, lines[0].Length)
                   .Select(x => lines.Max(y => y[x].Length))
                   .ToArray();

        foreach (var line in lines)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("   |   ", line.Select((x, i) => x.PadRight(widths[i], ' '))));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is the search and delete code I found somewhere on the internet I tried to put it in mine but I am sure that I butchered it.

```
private static void SearchStudents()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Text\students.txt");
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter student ID here: ");
            if (line == Console.ReadLine())
            {
                dem += 1;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Search result: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DeleteStudents()
    {
        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Text\students.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line != Console.ReadLine())
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }

        File.Delete("demo.txt");
        File.Move(tempFile, "demo.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("da xoa xong");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void UpdateStudents()
    {

    }
```

Sorry for my butchered English it is not my main language.

Comment: Please describe your question.

Comment: @LouisGo I edited it. Thank you!

Comment: do you have to use a `.txt` file? is this homework? this could be realized using serialization, which would result in a lot less effort and intrications

Comment: @MongZhu ye this is a homework it doesn't require using a text file but i want to try

Comment: please edit your post and try to pin point the problem and explain it a little more in detail. You qestion is almost good, but that essential point is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *Linq* and `File` class which can let you *query* the file and thus provide shorter and more readable code, e.g.

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  private static string FindStudentById(string id) {
    return File
      .ReadLines(@"C:\Text\students.txt")
      .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // to be on the safe side
      .Where(line => line.Split('\')[0].Trim().Equals(id.Trim()))
      .FirstOrDefault() ?? $"No student with id = {id} found";
  }

  private static void SearchStudents() {
    Console.Write("Enter student ID here: ");

    string id = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(FindStudentById(id)); 
  }
```

Same for student deletion, update, etc.

```
  private static string DeleteStudentById(string id) {
    var modifiedData = File
      .ReadLines(@"C:\Text\students.txt")
      .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
      .Where(line => !line.Split('\')[0].Trim().Equals(id.Trim()))
      .ToList();

    File
      .WriteAllLines(@"C:\Text\students.txt", modifiedData);
  }

  private static void DeleteStudents() {
    Console.Write("Enter student ID to delete here: ");

    string id = Console.ReadLine();

    DeleteStudentById(id); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making this object oriented. Create a student class, and a collection class and implement your functionality (add/update/search) in the collection class. Some pseudo code is below to get you started

```
public class Student()
{
    public string Id {get; set;
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Phone {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set; }
    public string Grade {get; set;}

    public Student()
    {
    }

}

public class Students: IEnumerator,IEnumerable
{
      private student[] _studentlist;
      int position = -1;

      //Create internal array in constructor.
      public Students()
      {
           //read you file into studentlist here
      }

      //IEnumerator and IEnumerable require these methods.
      public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
      {
         return (IEnumerator)this;
      }

      //IEnumerator
      public bool MoveNext()
      {
         position++;
         return (position < _studentlist.Length);
      }

      //IEnumerable
      public void Reset()
      {position = 0;}

      //IEnumerable
      public object Current
      {
         get { return _studentlist[position];}
      }

      public void Add(Student Student)
      {
          //Implement here
      }

      public void Save()
      {
          //persist to a file here
      } 

    public List<Student> Search(string Id)
    {
        return _studentlist.Where(s => s.Id = Id);
        //this could be expanded (e.g. pass in a student object and search on non empty properties)
    }

   }
```